# Mocked dependencies verification - Best practices

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have a simple question about best practices in unit test verifications.
Given this example:

```
@Test
public void methodUnderTest() {

    when(mockedDependency.someMethod()).thenReturn(someValue);

    int actual = classUnderTest.methodUnderTest();

    assertEquals(5, actual);
    verify(mockedDependency).someMethod();//should I do this?

}
```

As you can see I'm checking that my mock is being used. 
Should I do this?

With this verification if I change the implementation of the method (removing the usage of that dependency) my test is gonna fail and I'm forced to remove `when` and `verify`.

Without this verification if I change the implementation of the method my test is gonna pass but I will never know that in that test I'm mocking something that is not needed and when I will see that test again I will think that in my implementation I need that dependency.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where/how do you bind the `classUnderTest` to the `mockedDependency`? Does the `actual` result depend on `someValue` you use to mock?

Answer (score 1):

I've asked myself that question many times. I think you have to differentiate (translation: "it depends") between at least two cases:

**Case I**

The module under test is using the dependency to obtain some values or to perform some helper tasks. For example, `GenerateIncomeSheet()` might have dependencies on an `AccountsRepository` and a `TaxCalculator`.

In this case, do not verify that the dependencies' methods are called. The point of your module is not to use these dependencies, but to provide the correct result.

**Case II**

Some important, usually state changing operation has to be performed by a dependency. For example, the method under test should perform some checks and - depending on the result - add data to a repository.

In this case, you not only want to verify that the repository's method has been called (with the correct data), but also that it has *not* been called if the checks fail.